# How to delete a Component from Visual studio terminal?

Tags: linux, windows, bash, cmd, terminal

I created Reactjs project and In a hurry I created a folder and named it as Background. In Background folder I have two files, first file name it Background.js and second file name is Background.css. Now the problem is  I am not going to use that Component so I am trying to delete it. I tried to delete it but it is showing, The window is no longer responding
You can reopen or close the window or keep waiting.
My laptop configuration is very less I think that's why it is showing like this. So anyone please tell me how to delete Background folder along with Background.js and Background.css files from visual studion terminal. It will help me a lot thank you, If I am not clear with my doubt please put a comment.

If I am trying to delete Background folder it is showing like this
The window is no longer responding
You can reopen or close the window or keep waiting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it actually depends on your operating system. with *Nix (Linux, Unix) based OS you can use:

```
cd ~/path/to/your/folder

# to delete any files with the name starting with Background:
rm ./path/to/files/Background.*

# to delete the whole folder:
rm -rf ./path/to/folder
```

on windows:

```
# to delete the whole folder:
rmdir /s <complete path of folder suppose>

# to delete the files:
cd <to your folder>
del Background*
```